# Jenkins quits tests suddenly

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng

I am executing TestNg tests with Java Maven from Jenkins and everything seems to be okay but Jenkins stops executing the tests randomly and prompts:

```
[ERROR] Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-6', revision: '5f43a29cfc'
System info: host: '******', ip: '172.**.**.**', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[ERROR] There are test failures.

Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main(Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch(Maven35Main.java:178)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

[JENKINS] Recording test results
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  45:28 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-30T17:33:07+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This does not happen when i run the tests in my laptop (jenkins is on a windows vm).
What could cause this problem?

Comment: show your surefire plugin config

Comment: Jenkins goal and options are:
`clean test`

Comment: watching the logs it seems that the execution goes to the `onFinish` listener in the middle of the execution for apparently no reason.

`2020-10-01T11:13:13,776 [main] INFO  (TestNGListeners.java:232) - Suite finished: mySuite
[ERROR] Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-6', revision: '5f43a29cfc'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the test with Eclipse I found out that the problem is in the extent report.
I think this is the issue: https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/497

Jenkins wasn't logging anything of this:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:331)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:614)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.append.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.append.RawEntityConverter.convertAndApply(RawEntityConverter.java:27)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.AbstractProcessor.convertRawEntities(AbstractProcessor.java:98)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.createDomainFromJsonArchive(ExtentReports.java:377)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.createDomainFromJsonArchive(ExtentReports.java:392)
    at utils.ExcelDataProvider.test(ExcelDataProvider.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:821)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner$$Lambda$87/0x0000000100158840.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:588)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
```

Answer (score 0):

My surefire:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>anotherJavaProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>anotherJavaProject</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and this is the testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listeners.TestNGListeners"></listener>
    </listeners>
        <test name="test1">
        <parameter name="package" value="registration" />
        <parameter name="iterationstorun" value="1,2" />
        <parameter name="resource"
            value="src/main/resources/excel/test1.xlsx" />
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="exitonfail" value="no" />
        <parameter name="email" value="yes" />
        <classes>
            <class name="utils.Class" />
        </classes>
    </test>    
      <test name="test2">
        <parameter name="package" value="registration" />
        <parameter name="iterationstorun" value='1,2' />
        <parameter name="resource"
            value="src/main/resources/excel/test2.xlsx" />
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="exitonfail" value="no" />
        <classes>
            <class name="utils.Class" />
        </classes> 
    </test>   
</suite>
```